# Calculating simple and their syzygies in group algebras with GAP

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gap

Let $KG$ be a a group algebra for a finite field $K$ and a finite group $G$.

> Question 1: How to obtain using GAP a finite field extension $L$ such that $L$ is a splitting field for $KG$ and all the simple $LG$-modules?

> Question 2: Is there an easy way to calculate the n-th syzygies of the simple $LG$-modules using GAP?

> Question 3: Can one calculate the $Hom$-spaces for two given $LG$-modules using GAP?

Those are all very elementary questions but looking at the GAP manual there seems to be no easy commands that answer one of those questions.

Thanks for any help